# mvc application not adding newly created model to database

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, model

I recently added a new model to my MVC application that looks like this

```
namespace PIC_Program_1._0.Models
{
    public class DisposalOrder
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "DO ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }


        [DefaultValue("Pending")]
        public DOStatus Status { get; private set; }
        public decimal disposed { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DODetails> DisposalDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual Site sites { get; set; }
        public virtual Component Components { get; set; }
        public virtual Item Items { get; set; }
        public virtual Part Parts { get; set; }
        public bool deleted { get; set; }
        public bool hasBeenReleased { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

But when I run a add-migration and an update database, nothing is changed.

I created the model by right-clicking my Models folder, then typing "Add class" so it should be setup the right way. I'm stumped as to why it's not adding?

Comment: what does your db context class look like?

Comment: @JasonRoner Ahh it was missing the disposalorders db set, for some reason I was thinking it would've added it automatically